# django: How to avoid permission error on migration

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to deploy a django application on a virtual server running ubuntu 16.04.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

leads to the following traceback, after some models and fields have been created:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 179, in write_migration_files
    with open(writer.path, "wb") as fh:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org/aegeewww/migrations/0001_initial.py'
```

I also tried:

```
sudo python manage.py makemigrations
```

But since I am using a virtual environment, I get the following error, since django is not installed system wide:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

How can I fix this error? The python path is recognized correctly and django is obviously installed in the venv.

How do I have to set the permissions for the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need grant access for user to migrations folder:

```
sudo chown <your_username> <path_to_migrations_folder>
```

Comment: At first: thank you!  That was quite simple. 

Thing is, is there a general advice on which folder the user needs write permissions and on which not? or do i just have to give permissions to certain folders, everytime I run in to this problem? Or will thsi be the only time this happens?

Comment: In general you should run your django project from user which have access to directory with project.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov thanks bro, you have saved my time :)

Comment: Hey folks , if you need all inner folder permission, you have to add "-R" flag to the command as follows: `chmod -R <your_username> <path_to_migrations_folder>`

Answer (score 2):

The directory should be owned by the current user to make changes to it.
for instant solution use:
try: `sudo python3 manage.py makemigrations`

also try changing the chown by 
`sudo chown owner_name foldername(or)dir` 
ex:`sudo chown ubuntu db.sqlite3`  in the corresponding directory.

check by using:
`ls -la`
shows the permissions of files in current directory.

if nothing works out try changing read/write permissions of the file:
`sudo chmod permission_no dir_name`  permission_no 6644 or 777 both works fine.
ex: `sudo chmod 777 db.sqlite3`